# How do I Remove the entries with “?” in X - axis occupation?

Tags: r, ggplot2

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJ2Je.png)How do I Remove the entries with “?” in X - axis occupation ?[adult data set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xw9Vy.jpg)

Comment: You should post data with a reproducible example

Comment: try `dplyr::filter(data, Occupation != "?")`

Comment: This is my code: library(ggplot2)
mydata = read.csv("adult.csv")                                                                                              a <- ggplot(mydata) +
  aes(x = occupation, y = race) +
  labs(title = "Proportion of Different Races in Different Ocupations",
       x = "Occupation",
       y = "Proportion among Races") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 12, angle = 90, hjust = 1))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without using dplyr, you can also use something like:

```
data<-data[data$Occupation != "?",]
```

This will remove the rows with Occupation = "?" from your data completely.

If you want to keep those entries in your dataset, but just exclude them from the plot, you can adjust your code to be:

```
a <- ggplot(mydata[mydata$occupation != "?",] + aes(x = occupation, y = race) + labs(title = "Proportion of Different Races in Different Ocupations", x = "Occupation", y = "Proportion among Races") + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 12, angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```